# watch syntax for gulp, on function

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I've seen many times a `gulp.watch` variation as `gulp.watch(glob).on('change', cb)`, since it is not clearly explained in the gulp documentation, what is the difference from the classic `gulp.watch(glob, cb)`?

Thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly this is just syntactic sugar, as gulp.watch does emit an event when a change is detected.

Comment: Hi Elad you mean `.on` syntax is syntactic sugar, or the other way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Gulp.watch [documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb):

> Watch files and do something when a file changes. **This always returns
>   an EventEmitter that emits change events.**

Regarding your question on which is consider the "syntax sugar", The answer is

```
gulp.watch(glob, cb)
```

The binding of the passed cb occurs internally inside gulp.watch function body.